# MoveIt joint_state_publisher not publishing to robot_state_publisher

Tags: moveit, joint-state-publisher, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a 7-DOF manipulator with MoveIt and have calculated a series of joint vectors. I want to publish these joint vectors to the **joint states topic** so as to see the visualization in Rviz. However, after the implementation I did see the visualization in Rviz but there were "jumping backs" to the original manipulator configuration from time to time. I went into the problem and found that the correct messages were being published to the **joint states topic**, but **robot_state_publisher** was not receiving these messages, so no new tfs were updated (the manipulator still stayed at the original configuration, I think this is why there were "jumping backs") .

As a test, I used the **joint_state_publisher GUI** to publish messages to the **joint states topic** and I did see tf updates from **robot state publisher**. So what I do not understand is why publishing using GUI results in new tfs but publishing using codes does not.

I checked and ensured there were **joint_state_publisher** and **robot_state_publisher** nodes running and **robot_state_publisher** node did subscribe to the **joint states topic**.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207715/moveit-joint_state_publisher-not-publishing-to-robot_state_publisher/) by [Huitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22131/huitan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publishing JointState messages under the topic "/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states" instead of "joint_states" solved the problem. Joint state publisher rebroadcasts the messages so robot state publisher gets the new messages and updates the tfs.

---

Originally posted by [Huitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22131/huitan/) with karma: 63 on 2015-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edote](https://answers.ros.org/users/52093/edote/) on 2020-09-16**:
Hello,
I know this is old but how did you change the topic from joint_statess to fake_controller_joint states ?
I have the same issue, and I didn't find where the topic is defined in all the launch files of the moveit config package.
Best